# How come SignedExtra satisfies SignedExtension trait bound in substrate runtime?

Tags: runtime, substrate-node

In substrate runtime, https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/f60318f68687e601c47de5ad5ca88e2c3f8139a7/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L2106C10-L2106C21

```rust
pub type SignedExtra = (
    // all these structs implement the trait SignedExtension
    frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
    pallet_asset_conversion_tx_payment::ChargeAssetTxPayment<Runtime>,
);

/// Unchecked extrinsic type as expected by this runtime.
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic =
    generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, RuntimeCall, Signature, SignedExtra>;
```

But when you check the signature of generic::UncheckedExtrinsic

```rust
pub struct UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>
where
    Extra: SignedExtension,
{
    /// The signature, address, number of extrinsics have come before from
    /// the same signer and an era describing the longevity of this transaction,
    /// if this is a signed extrinsic.
    pub signature: Option<UncheckedSignaturePayload<Address, Signature, Extra>>,
    /// The function that should be called.
    pub function: Call,
}
```

It has trait bound for `SignedExtension` for type parameter `Extra`. How come the type SignedExtra be satisfying the trait bound? Assuming this is possible, what will happen when we call `valid` method for SignedExtra (from SignedExtension trait)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick that we often deploy in the Polkadot SDK. It uses a crate called [`impl_trait_for_tuple`](https://crates.io/crates/impl-trait-for-tuples). This crate aids with implementing a trait on a tuple type when all the tuple elements already implement the trait.

You can see it being used [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/dca142398e00786429d69eb8b9e4454499962b2a/substrate/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1591) for the `impl SignedExtension for Tuple`. This means that the tuple `(T0, T1 ..)` will implement `SignedExtension` when each `T` already implements `SignedExtension`. It is very useful, since we often need to aggregate multiple homogenous types into a tuple and not loose their trait implementations.